# Tumblr CSS positioning

Tags: css

I'm making a two column Tumblr theme and I need to fix this weird CSS positioning issue I'm having. If you look at the picture provided you can see that there's a gap in between two pictures in the first column. This happens when a picture is smaller than the `max-width` I guess the rest of the width it just filled with blank space. How can I fix it?

Code: 
http://pastebin.com/eY4EsQKH

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oexgE.png

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kQVNd

Comment: Put the code into http://jsFiddle.net for us to experiment with, it's much easier to have something to play with when diagnosing problems.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kQVNd/

Comment: So the problem is that your pictures are not actually in 2 columns, they are in rows. Picture 1 is top left, picture 2 is top right, picture 3 is below picture 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**1.** Divide the content in two columns like this:

```
<div class="column">
            <!-- articles -->
</div>


<div class="column">
            <!-- articles -->
</div>
```

**2.** Add this CSS:

```
.column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/kQVNd/5/)**

Comment: I get it a bit more now but the problem is that the images are not hardcoded. Using Tumblr so the images are in these blocks

`{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}
    
        <article class="photopost">
          <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
        </article>
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}`

Comment: @user3693206 and you don't have control over individual parts of the data you receive?

Comment: @user3693206 does the function to fetch posts return a JSON string? Because in that case, you could divide it and append each half to each column.